# Can Excel use wildcards to determine if a cell contains specific text?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

If A1 contains *miles*, the following evaluation is true:

`=IF(A1="miles",1,0)`

If A1 contains *miles and miles*, the following evaluation return false:

`=IF(A1="*miles*",1,0)`

Every resource I find uses (what looks to me) like a backdoor way of identifying the string, by searching for its location:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("miles",A1)),1,0)`

This accomplishes the task, but can Excel use wildcards to evaluate whether or not a longer string contains a smaller string?

Comment: I don't know if there is some known constraint, or if I'm misunderstanding or misusing that type of logic.  It seems like such a simple use of the wildcards I thought I would ask the community if there is something I'm missing.

Comment: Removed the "Why" from your question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH("*miles*",A1,0)))
```

Returns `TRUE` if A1 contains `miles` and `FALSE` if it does not. (Case insensitive)

Answer (score 6):

You can also use Countif() with wildcards

```
=COUNTIF(A1,"*miles*")
```

Returns a 0 when not found. Perfect for IF statements.